# Spring Core: Unable to create a basic request.What am I missing?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

previously I was building projects with Spring boot and everything was nice and automated for me. Now I am trying to learn a bit of Spring core, and I am stuck at a basic thing for a couple of days unable to find what the issue is in my project. I am trying to create a basic request which always ends in a 404 not found.

```
@Controller
public class Test {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String doStuff(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

The index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

the pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I can't understand what I am missing, when I deploy the war on the local tomcat, and go to `http://localhost:8080/home` I always get a 404. Is my package structure for spring core wrong? I have:

```
src>java>com>example>Test
```

for the controller class and

```
src>main>webapp>index.jsp
```

for the view. I have even created a resources folder inside the main folder and added the index.jsp there, but same issue.
This is everything I have, with spring boot this would have worked no problem, am I missing a configuration, for the viewresolver or something?

Comment: With SpringCore, you need a lot more configuration classes to activate WebMVC and View support. Can you provide your configuration classes ?

Comment: so nothing works until those config classes are in place?That is all i have, what config classes do i need to write in order to make it possible for that request to work?Can you show me in a post the steps that i need to take please?

Comment: Check this. If it doesn't work after that, edit your post and ask another question : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial

Comment: but am i actually forced to use MVC when working with spring core?can't i make a basic get request without enableing it like i do with spring boot?

Comment: You do not want only do a basic request when I see your code, you want to resolve a view...

Comment: is there a way i can use html/jsp without configuring anything?The only thing i can do with what i have so far is return a simple String as the method return type?